# A Talking Seat - Script Help (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: python, audio, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2, raspberry-pi-zero

**Project Aim:** Create a seat that when you sit on it, audio starts. When you leave, the audio stops. Next time someone sits down, the audio begins again. Each time it is a random track, different from the last.

**Context**: Outside with access to power

**How it can work (I think):** I’m wondering if it is possible with using a Raspberry Pi and PIR Sensor (plus some other bits and pieces?). Basically, when someone moves into the range of the PIR sensor, this event is detected and sends an input to a GPIO pin on the Pi. With the right script, this can then fire an event – e.g. play a random audio file from micro SD card. Does this sound correct/doable?

**Help!:** I believe its not too abstract an idea or function, that has probably been done before. But I just can’t seem to find exactly what I’m looking for, where someone has already written a script I can use/modify. So I’d love to know, do you think this idea is doable/achievable? And, where acatly do you recommend I can track down a pre-made script/instruction on making it a reality.

If you know someone who could write such a script, please do put me in contact.

*Thanks*!

Comment: Welcome to SO Frogga. Alas this is not a programming question.

Comment: Thanks Mike :) Is there a better place I could post this question? I assumed it was a programming question as such, because I'm in need of someone to help with writing a script to manage this task?

Comment: it sounds like you are asking someone to write some code for you rather than asking about a question in any code you have written. Whilst people are happy to help answering andy programming questions you have SO is not a code writing service. Your question is better suited to https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks Mike, I actually have tried over there and was told "This is a general programming question, not Pi specific". I'm of course just starting out and trying to find the best place to ask this, didn't mean to offend! So I'm a bit stuck where to go...

Comment: If it is asking about GPIO on a Pi board it seems pretty specific to me. If this is a programming question I would suggest that you share the code you have tried so far so users can show you where you are getting stuck.

Comment: Thanks Mike! Will post some more info once I have a bit of a start. Unfortunately I am starting a bit from the ground up and thought this was a good place to begin.

Comment: I'd suggest that starting with a basic project or course would be an easier place to start.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not that hard to realize. You have to come up with an idea for a sensor that you can build into your chair, I would recommend just a simple one that works like a push button: when someone sits down, you got a connection the RasPi can recognize. After doing that make sure, your RaspberryPi has power, a GPIO connection to the sensor and speakers attached.
The Script is also quite simple and its structure would look like this:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import simpleaudio # just as an example, was the first one I found online

sound = 'path/to/your/soundfile.wav'

def playSound(directory):
    play = simpleaudio.WaveObject.from_wave_file(directory)
    play.play()

try:
    while True: 
        if GPIO.input(numberofyourgpio):
            play_sound(sound)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

Finally you can set this to start after booting the RaspberryPi and you will never have to care about it not being started anymore.

Comment: Fabian, you are too kind. Thanks, that is a great start and I'm glad to hear it's not too hard. Is there something simple I could add for the following:
- Each time the audio starts up, it plays a random track
- Each track plays to the end, before looking for another input from the sensor (and making sure it is not being interupted half way through)

Thanks for your help so far :)

Comment: Yes that is possible - random is actually a module built in python (means you need to add "import random" at the top) and every RaspberryPi has a chip on the board dedicated just to generate random numbers. Because of the fact that the script is single treaded, your sound will always play until the end.
For the randomizing effect this is a bit more tricky, but also not hard to realize: you need a list of paths (looks like this: list = ['path0' , 'path1', 'path2']). Then you go and instead of the sound argument you parse in "random.choice(list)"
This should do your job quite well I'd think :D

Comment: Thanks again, very useful! Love your work :)